# Google Visualization API : client side in JAVA

Tags: java, api, google-visualization

Does anybody know about a JAVA API for the *client side* of the [Google DataSource Prototocol](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source.html). I know about the server side [JAVA API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_about.html) to generate the JSON DataTable. But I do not find anything that takes the generated JSON data-table and recreate a JAVA DataTable instance for instance.

I do not want to use GWT classes but pure standalone JAVA application.

Thanks.